# how can i make sweet2alert don't show again message?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

I have been trying to hide this message if I click `"<span onclick='save()'>Don't Show Again</span>",` using localstorage but it's not working. how do i do that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(localStorage.getItem("DontShow")) {
        $("#save").hide();
    }
    $(document).on("click", "#save", function() {
        localStorage.setItem("DontShow", "true");
    });

  Swal.fire({
            allowOutsideClick: false,
            allowEscapeKey: false,
            allowEnterKey: false,
            showCancelButton: true,
            icon: 'info',
            title: 'Title',
            html: '<div class="swal-left"><b>Text</b><br>Text</div>',

            confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
            cancelButtonText: "Close",
            confirmButtonText: "<span onclick='save()'>Don't Show Again</span>",
            footer: '<a href>Why do I have this issue?</a>'
          });

  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

add this after the swal.fire function

```
.then((result) => {
  if (result.isConfirmed)
      'function that hides here'

});
```